# Como obtener el Texto de un Label que esta dentro de un ListView dinámico Xamarin Forms PCL

Tags: xamarin, listview

Tengo un ListView en el muestro una lista de noticias, Quiero seleccionar un item he ir a otra PageActivity y mostrar el detalle ampliado de la noticia. no hay problemas en pasar estos datos por medio del constructor, el caso es que el contenido de mis item se crean en tiempo de ejecución y lo que quiero es saber como puedo acceder a estos datos y pasarlos a otra page, dicho mas claro tengo una imagen y 2 label que no pueden ser accedidos por medio de un x:name por razones obvias soy un novato en xamarin espero crecer algún día podrían ayudarme chicos.

```
      private void OnItemSelected(object sender,SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.Navigation.PushAsync(new ExpandedNews("Title","News","Image"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Yorman say: "+ item.ToString());
    }
```

=====================================================

```
<ListView x:Name="listNews"  HasUnevenRows="true"  ItemTapped="OnItemSelected"  RowHeight="55" SeparatorColor="Gray"  BackgroundColor="Transparent">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding="5">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="160"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="70"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Image}" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                       <Label ClassId="lbtt" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Black"  Text="{Binding Title}"></Label>
                       <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"   Text="{Binding Description}" Font="Small"  TextColor="Gray"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Al final resulto de esta manera :

```
   async void clickNews(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var NewsItem = args.SelectedItem as NewsItem;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ExpandedNews(new NewsViewModel(NewsItem)));

    }
```

´´
´´

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ExpandedNews : ContentPage
{
     NewsViewModel viewModel;



    public ExpandedNews(NewsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;

     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando estás en el manejador del evento ItemSelected, te llegará el objeto SelectedItem como parte del SelectedItemChangedEventArgs, este objeto representa el elemento que fue seleccionado.

Puedes obtener el elemento de tu lista (digamos que es de tipo ElementoLista) usando e.SelectedItem, así de esta forma:

```
var elem = e.SelectedItem as ElementoLista;
```

Y ahí tendrás tus propiedades Image, Title y Description. No necesitas acceder a los elementos visuales (Label, Image).

Incluso puedes pasar ese mismo objeto como parámetro para la página de detalle, para poder bindearlo sin tener que hacer mucho código.

Comment: esta resulta bien ! Gracias a todos.

Comment: Qué bueno que te sirva la respuesta, por favor márcala como aceptada. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar la propiedad e.SelectedItem y deberia venir el elemento que estas usando a nivel de contexto para tu grid.

Puedes castearlo a tu tipo haciendole unboxing:

> MiClase contexto = (MiClase)e.SelectedItem;

Answer (score 0):

debes realizar la conversión del item al tipo de viewmodel de la lista:

```
private void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (ItemViewModel)e.SelectedItem;
        if (item == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Title))
            return;
        this.Navigation.PushAsync(new ExpandedNews(item.Title, item.Description, item.Image)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = (e.SelectedItem as youritemtype).Propiedad;
```

Comment: Veo que ya tienes cierta reputación en [so]. Deberías saber que una respuesta en la que no explicas absolutamente se considera de baja calidad.

Comment: Como te dice Pikoh, has de mejorarla añadiendo epxlicacion. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo